# How can I do this query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

can You help me in this situation

I have three tables

first stored usersgroup
ugroup - primary key
groupname - group name

second stored users
uid - primary key
ugroup - int
username 
and so on
.....

third table has list of teachers for each user
teachId - primary key
uid - int
..........

so this query work fine in controller

```
var viewUsers= db.UsersGroup.Include("Users").ToList();
```

and in view

I can outp all my groups and users which are in them

```
@foreach(var ug in @Model.viewUsers)
{
ug.groupName
  foreach(var u in ug.Users)
    {
         &nbsp;&nbsp;u.UserName;
    }
}
```

so but I want to build table in view to show this info:

```
<caption>GroupName</caption>
<th>UserName</th><th>Count of teachers</th>
<td> John Smith</td><td>3</td>
```

So how should i build a query to build table in my View like above?

And I if you can give some link where can i read about how can i use EF to make varios queries to my database (like joins uinions and otheres) and I don't understand how work Include() method
i try to chnge my prev string like : `db.UserGroups.Include(ug => ug.Users)` but it does not work :(

Thank You.

Comment: Have you used a viewmodel? Can you show us your viewmodel code?

Comment: I am not sure about the structure of your tables, but you can include both if they are structured as I suppouse var viewUsers= db.UsersGroup.Include("Users").include("teachers").ToList();

Comment: No I havent Use ViewModel

Comment: Yeas I can include them both but how can I fetch once moore column with count of the teachers for eah user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var viewUsers= db.UsersGroup.Include("Users.Teachers").ToList();
```

and then in the view you can get the Teacher list for each user

```
@foreach(var ug in @Model.viewUsers)
    {
      ug.groupName

      foreach(var u in ug.Users)
        {
             &nbsp;&nbsp;u.UserName;

             <th>u.Teachers.Count</th>

             foreach(var teacher in u.Teachers)
             {
                 <td>teacher.Name</td>
             }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Moment I try to do like you advice

Comment: Neil  Thank You very much... every think is work.... can you give some link where can i read bout all aspect of this topic?

Comment: @user3323401, If the answer is correct, please mark it.